# Saving image in uv editor with seams showing

Tags: uv-image-editor

When saving the png from the uv editor, how do you make sure the seams show too with the exported image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You have to export it separately:

[image]

The UV layout isn't supposed to be contained in a texture usually. It's supposed to be a tool to help you to create the texture, not something displayed as the object's texture itself. Unless you're really going for something special.